# Are questions about Zune desktop software on topic? Skydrive?

Tags: discussion, scope

Personally I knew nothing of Zune until I needed it to do things with my new phone. So I've got a bunch of questions about Zune which I'd love to ask here, and to me they feel like they're phone related.

But others might not feel the same way, which is why I'm checking here.

Same thing with SkyDrive and Live.com, and even Hotmail and all this other peripheral stuff that I've had to engage with since getting the phone, and wouldn't really be aware of except for their usage alongside my phone.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, only is as much as they are related to the phone. A few example of on-topic questions:

- How do I set up wireless sync in zune?
- Is there a way to merge duplicate hotmail contacts in my people hub?
- How can I access SkyDrive documents from my phone?

off-topic questions would be along the lines of:

- How can I setup a playlist in zune
- How do I filter messages in hotmail
- Is there a desktop client for skydrive?

Comment: Agreed.  Super User and Web Apps should be able to cover non-WP-related aspects of desktop and web software respectively.