# Suggested FAQ wording around the scope of this site

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, top-7

After reaching what I think is the most activity this thread is going to have (at this stage of the beta), and no one objecting to the changes; I have taken the liberty of adding the content below to the FAQ. **This doesn't mean it is set in stone**. Can still always refine it over time, but I feel like this is a great start for now.

---

There have been quite a few questions now on what the scope of this site should be.

- [Are speculative questions on topic?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/are-speculative-questions-on-topic)
- [Questions about specific apps are eligible?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/questions-about-specific-apps-are-eligible)
- [What should we do about legal questions?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/what-should-we-do-about-legal-questions)
- [Are questions about Zune desktop software on topic? Skydrive?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/are-questions-about-zune-desktop-software-on-topic-skydrive)
- [Are Windows Phone programming questions appropriate for the site?](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-windows-phone-programming-questions-appropriate-for-the-site)
- [and many more](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope)

I was thinking about how we should word all this in our FAQ, and the [Android.SE version](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq) seems perfect. I propose we adopt what they have (tweaking it for our platform of course).

Please feel free to suggest edits, or if you think we need to wait on this - speak up.

---

#### What kind of questions can I ask here?

Windows Phone - Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Windows Phone operating system.

If your question generally covers...

- Using your Windows Phone device
- Using a particular app on your device
- Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your device

then this is the right place to ask. Basically, what problem (with your phone) are you trying to solve?

#### What about other Windows Phone related questions?

Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here:

- Developing/programming for Windows Phone (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)
- Marketing your app or doing market research
- Issues with the Marketplace from the point of view of a developer or publisher
- Recommendations, like "Which phone is better?" or "Can you suggest an app that does X?"
- Speculative questions, like "When will X be available in my country?" or "Why does Company X do this?"
- Legal questions, such as "Will X void my warranty?"
- Windows Phone-independent phone questions, such as "Does Carrier X have prepaid plans?"
- Questions around the Xbox Live and Windows Live services unless the question pertains to integration on the phone. For example, a question like "How can I change my Xbox Live password?" Is off topic, but "How can I enable the Xbox Live integration" would be OK.
  Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.

Comment: Just amazing perfectly!!! But what about "How can I take screen shot"? How can you fit in this? For me it was not so clear about we are or are not accept this.

Comment: That seems like a perfect question to ask. It doesn't matter there is no built in function to do it; it still is a valid question

Answer (score 1):

I think we should also add "issues around the Windows Live service, or Xbox Live service" to the off topic list. Although the phone uses these services, I feel like they don't fit and better answers will be given from MS support.

This doesn't mean people can't ask questions about them when **it is about integration with the phone**, but questions like [Unable to update country on Live account?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/113/unable-to-update-country-on-live-account) would be off topic as this has nothing to do with WP